# Able to start hybrid generic server but couldn't able to add hybrid generic service

Tags: java, light-4j

Generated generic hybrid server and hybrid service using light4j codegen tool. When i start the generic hybrid server, it works. But when we start the hybrid server with service, it stops a wierd error like below. Not sure whether service handler annotation or schema syntax has been changed. rpc routers and security packages are available in gserver. Removed the todo statements in logback.xml.  Kept only one rpc annotation and handler but still it didn't worked out.

```
../generic-service/target/gservice-1.0.0.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
../generic-service/target/gservice-1.0.0.jar: line 2: G▒Ncom/PK: No such file or directory
../generic-service/target/gservice-1.0.0.jar: line 3: G▒Ncom/networknt/PK: No such file or directory
../generic-service/target/gservice-1.0.0.jar: line 4: G▒Ncom/networknt/gservice/PK: No such file or directory
../generic-service/target/gservice-1.0.0.jar: line 5: G▒Ncom/networknt/gservice/handler/PK: No such file or directory
../generic-service/target/gservice-1.0.0.jar: line 6: G▒Nconfig/PK: No such file or directory
../generic-service/target/gservice-1.0.0.jar: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
../generic-service/target/gservice-1.0.0.jar: line 7: G▒N4▒ï▒O0com/networknt/gservice/handler/HelloWorld1.class▒R▒n▒@=▒;!▒%\˥▒▒DR▒l+▒▒D▒▒VA³co▒)▒n▒Y7▒▒▒        ▒▒G!fmK▒TH▒▒▒윝s▒▒▒▒?<▒▒&▒▒▒▒▒&▒▒nܫcS▒▒▒4▒g▒Nw(Pyab%▒▒V▒t▒▒▒p▒p▒▒(L▒▒%▒]+nBs▒▒Ad▒R+▒0▒▒vr<W▒▒"%'▒▒e▒J▒▒▒$▒▒▒ȼ,▒▒▒▒▒▒uf!=▒7;7▒▒▒▒U?8'
```

If some one could help me getting some detailed log also, will debug further.

I followed the [article](https://networknt.github.io/light-hybrid-4j/tutorial/helloworld/).

Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: why this is downvoted? i tried various combinations of modifying schema and removing handler still getting errors?

Comment: The article is very old and I will remove it now. All the new tutorials are located here  https://doc.networknt.com/tutorial/hybrid/

Comment: I looked at the light codegen web article it looks like it works in docker environment.Is there tutorial without docker? (as i am using windows)

Comment: I am writing a hello world example and it will be used standalone and then docker. This is the framework we used most internally as it is the most efficient in term development and production cost.

Comment: I have completed the first part of the Hello World tutorial with the first service loaded by the server instance. You can find it at https://doc.networknt.com/tutorial/hybrid/hello-world/

Comment: Thanks steve, this tutorial works fine without any issues.

Comment: I have added the second part with service2 and also record a video to walk through the process. https://doc.networknt.com/tutorial/hybrid/hello-world/

Comment: Yes i tried both and it works.

Answer (score 0):

light-hybrid-4j is a serverless framework and it is very efficient in terms of memory usage as we can put hundreds of services into the same server instance and all of them are still independently developed. Almost all our internal services today are using this framework along with light-kafka for event sourcing. The new light-portal backend services are examples.

https://lightapi.net
https://dev.lightapi.net